# How to select all checkbox using jquery or javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I have multiple checkboxes , there is a checkbox with select all name, now i want that when some tick
    the select all checkbox, then all the checkbox must be selected. I think this will be in jquery.
    any tutorial link or codes with hints would be appreciated.the code snip is under...

```
<input type="checkbox" value="">Select All<br/>
<input type="checkbox" value="">A<br/>
<input type="checkbox" value="">B<br/>
<input type="checkbox" value="">C<br/>
<input type="checkbox" value="">D<br/>
<input type="checkbox" value="">E<br/> 
<input type="checkbox" value="">F<br/>
<input type="checkbox" value="">G<br/>
<input type="checkbox" value="">H<br/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<input type="checkbox" id="exp" />Tick All Checkbox<br/>
<input type="checkbox" value="demo1" class="subchkbox"/>No 1<br/>
<input type="checkbox" value="demo2" class="subchkbox"/>No 2<br/>
<input type="checkbox" value="demo3" class="subchkbox"/>No 3<br/>
<input type="checkbox" value="demo4" class="subchkbox"/>No 4<br/>
<input type="checkbox" value="demo5" class="subchkbox"/>No 5<br/>

<sctipt type="text/javascript">
/*Include the jquery library 1.9.1*/
  $(document).ready(function() {
  $('#exp').click(function(event) {  
    if(this.checked) { 
        $('.subchkbox').each(function() { 
            this.checked = true;       
        });
    }else{
        $('.subchkbox').each(function() { 
            this.checked = false;                   
        });         
    }
  });

  });
[the fiddle is here][1]
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/wf8993rm/   this is the fiddle

Comment: Shouldn't have to use `.each` - just do `$('.subchkbox').prop("checked", this.checked)` - either way - +1 for the common classes and the ID on the select all.

Answer (score 3):

This should check all checkboxes when you check the `"Select All"` one, and also uncheck all checkboxes when you uncheck it.

```
$("#selectAll").click(function () {
    $(":checkbox").not(this).prop("checked", $(this).is(":checked"));
});
```

If you don't want the uncheck behavior:

```
$("#selectAll").click(function () {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $(":checkbox").not(this).prop("checked", true);
    }
});
```

But of course, you must identify it. Do it by adding the `id="selectAll"` attribute (or any other id you wish, just make sure you change the JavaScript code as well):

```
<input type="checkbox" value="" id="selectAll">Select All<br/>
<input type="checkbox" value="">A<br/>
<input type="checkbox" value="">B<br/>
<input type="checkbox" value="">C<br/>
<input type="checkbox" value="">D<br/>
<input type="checkbox" value="">E<br/> 
<input type="checkbox" value="">F<br/>
<input type="checkbox" value="">G<br/>
<input type="checkbox" value="">H<br/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Using *jQuery* :

```
 $("input[type=checkbox]").prop({ checked : true })
```

#### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uxa0ravz/)

Using pure *JavaScript* :

```
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]')
Object.keys(inputs).forEach(function(i){
   inputs[i].checked = true
})
```

#### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uxa0ravz/2/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$("checkboxContainer").find("input[type='checkbox']").each(function() {
    $(this).prop("checked", true);
});
```

I think using `.find()` is faster when selecting multiple elements.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this in plain JS, it's also pretty simple.

You just have to loop through all of the inputs and set `checked` to `true` (or `false`), which isn't very efficient.

```js
document.getElementById("all").addEventListener("change", function() {
  if (this.checked) {
    var boxes = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
    for (var i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) {
      if (boxes[i].type === "checkbox") {
        boxes[i].checked = true;
      }
    }
  } else {
    var boxes = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
    for (var i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) {
      if (boxes[i].type === "checkbox") {
        boxes[i].checked = false;
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" value="" id="all">Select All
<br/>
<input type="checkbox" value="">A
<br/>
<input type="checkbox" value="">B
<br/>
<input type="checkbox" value="">C
<br/>
<input type="checkbox" value="">D
<br/>
<input type="checkbox" value="">E
<br/>
<input type="checkbox" value="">F
<br/>
<input type="checkbox" value="">G
<br/>
<input type="checkbox" value="">H
<br/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Derived from the current answer marked as correct, [it can all be much simpler](http://jsfiddle.net/wf8993rm/1/):

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#exp').click(function(event)
    {
        $('.subchkbox').prop({
            checked: $(this).prop('checked')
        });    
    });    
});
```